# count number of columns with a value of 0 in line/row 230

Tags: linux, text-processing, awk

I want to count the number of columns with a value of 0 in line 230, how do I do this?

This gives me the number of 0s in column 230:

```
awk ' $230==0{c0++};END{print "Missing: "c0;}' file
```

but I want number of 0s in row 230

Comment: `awk ' NR==230{c0++};END{print "Missing: "c0;}' file` doesn't work?

Comment: No, this doesn't work it returns a value of one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
perl -lane '$. == 230 && print scalar grep /^0$/, @F'
```

Answer (score 2):

Iterate over the fields of the 230-th record, check if there are `0`, and keep a count if so:

```
awk 'NR==230 {for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i==0) {c++}; print c; exit}' file.txt
```

**Example:** Checking the second record:

```
% cat file.txt
1 2 3 5
0 0 2 3

% awk 'NR==2 {for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i==0) {c++}; print c; exit}' file.txt
2
```

Comment: This doesn't work, when I try specifying another value it returns the same number as when I ask for the number of 0s.

Comment: why don't you provide sample set of input and expect output count

Comment: @AlanGarciaElfring Like Kamaraj said, you need to show where it's not working.